# Understanding SAS Cube Restoration

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, restore, bids, olap-cube

I am currently working in MS SQL Server 2008 R2 to update one of our processes. This package updates a Cube as the final step.

I have searched several guides on Cube backup and restoration online and believe I've found a solid method for restoration. I've followed the guides and backed up an old Cube which we no longer use with a .abf file (I wanted to get the hang of it with something unimportant). I was able to set things up with the proper file paths and run XML to restore this database. The folder in which the data resides was updated and it appears there were no errors in performing this restoration.

To check if the restore worked properly, I went into the Cube in MS Visual Studio and edited the Data Source View to include a new table. I also added and deleted a measure each from the .cube file itself. However after performing the restoration, these changes were still in Visual Studio. This Cube is quite out of date and so I am wondering do I need to process the cube after the restoration to complete a restore? PS: this Cube and the Cube I will need to update are MOLAP.

My knowledge of Cubes is limited so any background information to help me understand would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry if this is a bit long winded, thank you

Comment: Firstly, cube backups are not usually done because a cube is built from source data and if you lose your cube data you usually just build it again. Secondly, the thing you changed in visual studio is the cube _source_. It's not 'compiled' into your cube until you publish it. The thing you backed up is the actual published built cube.

Comment: So typical lifecycle of a cube is: 1. Create cube definition in Visual Studio; 2. Publish cube definition to SSAS server; 3. On SSAS server, build cube from data sources. So hopefully you can understand the published cube on the SSAS server containing data and the cube definition inside visual studio are two separate things. The .abf file you created is from the published cube contain data. The visual studio thing you edited contains the 'source code'. I think it's more important to back up your source code (i.e. with version control like TFS or Git) rather than backing up your published cube.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.

Comment: So for my scenario, what I'm looking to do is restore the cube to a previous state if the updates in the package change either the source or the metadata in an undesirable way. If I back up the source data for the cube and restore it, then run the version of the process before updates (& deploy / publish the cube), will it return to its previous state?

Comment: After doing more research, I've found that the cube uses the Process Full Processing Option within the Analysis Services Processing Task. In my understanding, this means each time the package is run, the cube will drop all the current data it is holding and repopulate with data from the data sources. Which means as long as I back up the data sources, I can restore those and re-process the cube to restore it to the former state before updates I intend to make. Please let me know if I'm missing something here, thanks.

Comment: _restore the cube to a previous state if the updates in the package change either the source or the metadata in an undesirable way_. Managing this would normally be achieved by having a test environment. Users test it and approve it then it and only then does it get migrated to prod. I guess before you migrate to prod you could backup the cube then restore it if need be.